# How to find index of object in array with latest date

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects in an array. Each object has a date field. Here is a method I wrote to retrieve the index of the object with the newest date, works fine:

```
GetIndexOfLatestDate()
   {
    var indexOfLatestDate:number = 0;
    
    var maxDate:number = new Date(this.objArray[0].date).getTime();
    
    for(var nIndex:number = 1; nIndex < this.m_objArray.length; nIndex++)
    {
      if(new Date(this.objArray[nIndex].date).getTime() > maxDate)
      {
        maxDate = new Date(this.objArray[nIndex].date).getTime();
        indexOFLatestDate = nIndex;
      }
    }

    return indexOfLatestDate;
   }
```

How can this be written (much) more succinctly?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function that javascript provides. This solution also doesn't loop through the array multiple times, and it calls `new Date().getTime()` once per date.

```
GetIndexOfLatestDate()
{
   if (this.objectArr === null || this.objectArr.length === 0) {
      return null;
   }

   return this.objectArr.reduce((accum, value, index) => {
      const newDate = new Date(value.date).getTime();
      return newDate > accum.maxDate ? {index, maxDate: newDate} : accum;
   }, {index: 0, maxDate: new Date(this.objectArr[0].date).getTime()}).index;
}
```

---

if this looks too confusing, here is an expanded version that's easier to follow if you are new to the reduce function.

```
GetIndexOfLatestDate()
{
   // check if object arr is empty
   if (this.objectArr === null || this.objectArr.length === 0) {
      return null;
   }

   // set default accumulator for first passthrough
   const defaultAccum = {  
         index: 0, 
         maxDate: new Date(this.objectArr[0].date).getTime()
    }

   const maxValueWithIndex = this.objectArr.reduce((accum, value, index) => {
      // set formatted date to prevent multiple Date() calls
      const newDate = new Date(value.date).getTime();

      // if the new date is larger than the current largest date, set
      // the accumulator to the new largest date and its index
      if (newDate > accum.maxDate)
         accum = {
            index: index, 
            maxDate: newDate
         };
      } 
      
      // return the current accumulator, i.e. the current largest date
      return accum;
    }, defaultAccum);

   // return the index of the latest date
   return maxValueWithIndex.index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `reduce`, something like:

```
index = this.objArray.reduce((accum, value, index) => {
   if(!accum){
      accum = {
          index,
          maxDate: value.date
      };
   } else {
      if(accum.maxDate.getTime() > value.date.getTime()){
          accum = {
              index,
              maxDate: value.date
          };
      }
   }

   return accum;
}

}, null).index;
```

Comment: why are you using `null` as the default value? why not have `{index: 0, maxDate: this.objArray[0].date}` and then you don't need to check if there is an accumulator every time

Comment: Thats another possibility. But yours will fail if `objArray` is empty, and it should be `{ index: 0, maxDate: this.objArray[0].data }`.

Comment: The original code that OP posted will also fail if `objArray` is empty. So I think it's safe to say they are/should check the object before running the reduce

Comment: No, reduce will not execute if objArray is empty... but will fail if objArray is null.

Comment: I'm not talking about you. the original post has `new Date(this.objArray[0].date).getTime()` which will fail if objArray is null

Comment: Oh, you said "before running the reduce", my solution is the only one using reduce hehehe. Yup, the OP code will fail too if null

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using built-in function like this

```js
const array1 = [{date: '2/5/2021'}, {date: '3/11/2019'}, {date: '12/9/2022'}];

const dateArray = array1.map(({date}) => {return new Date(date)})
const maxDate = Math.max(...dateArray);
const indexMaxElem = dateArray.findIndex(dateObj => dateObj.getTime() === maxDate)
console.log(indexMaxElem)
```

It is less efficient though, since it needs to do multiple pass through the array

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateArr = [];
objArray.forEach(item => {

    //  extract the dates from the source array to form new array
    dateArr.push(objArray.date.getTime();
});

// find the maximum date in this array, which will have the same index
indexOfLatest = dateArr.findIndex(Math.max(...dateArr));
```

Comment: This has good intention, but will not work because `findIndex` accepts a function, not a value, so you will need to be more explicit like `dateArr.findIndex(s => s === Math.max(...dateArr))`. Also you can use `map` instead of `forEach` for a bit cleaner syntax

Answer (score 0):

```js
GetIndexOfLatestDate(objArray){
  let max = objArray.reduce(function (a, b){ return new Date(a.date) > new 
     Date(b.date) ? a : b; });
  return objArray.indexOf(max);
}
```